# Can I combine 2 UnrealEngine forks?

Tags: unreal-4, git, flex

I am using Daz Gen 8 characters and clothes in my project.

After I read [this](https://www.daz3d.com/forums/discussion/134926/adding-dual-quaternion-support-to-unrealengine4-images-inside) I decided to use a fork of UE4 which uses Dual Quaternion Skinning.

Basically if you use Daz characters under UE4, they going to distort better if you use DQS, which UE4 doesn't support by default.
You can get the DQS modded engine from [here](https://github.com/AlienRenders/UnrealEngine/tree/4.25-mod).

I compiled it and I managed to get all my stuff from my original project to a DQS one.

No problem.

But I also need a soft body and a clothing solution in the project.

4.25 has a clothing solution and it does work fine, but there is no soft body, that I know about...

So there are a few options:

1. Vico Dynamics from the Marketplace
2. using a [Flex branch of UE4](https://github.com/xoyojank/UnrealEngine/tree/4.22-FleX)
3. if you know any more please please let me know

Tested Vico, and it works fine for simple meshes, up to 20k poligons. Over that the editor becomes unresponsive... But this works with my modded DQS engine.

The latest version of an UE4 branch with Flex is 4.22. I could get this compiled and running.

I would like to know if I can merge the 2 repositiories (4.22 DQS and Flex) into one, and source build it...
What software or workflow do you recommend to do merge these big branches of UE4?
I guess there will be quite a few conflicts, because Flex distorts the mesh in it's own way, so does the DQS version of Unreal...